# Create New user groups in joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

Is it possible to create extra groups i.e. Staff. i am using joomla 1.5 version

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible but it's a bit tricky, luckily the joomla docs wrote something about this ...
http://docs.joomla.org/Custom_user_groups
Hope this will help you ...

Comment: thanks for your answer i was read this one but i can't understand last step . please explain to me